# detecting heartbeat peakpower using iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, heartbeat

i want to detect heart rate using iphone sdk does someone knows any method for calculating heartbeat rate?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it doesn't look like you're putting forth much of your own effort. Perhaps if you described something you have tried, but which didn't work, and asked for some pointers on a new direction, rather than asking how, and then asking for source.

Comment: i've tried mic blowing sample i don't know how to calculate heart rate using accelerometer or microphone.Actually i want to calculate by recording heart beat sound and then filter that sound but don't know how to filter beat sound only from an audio?

Comment: Try a fast Fourier transform on the input: my guess is that it should be much easier to filter noise there than on the raw input.

Comment: @ Charles Stewart what is fast Fourier transform and how do i implement this

Answer (score 2):

Fast Fourier Transform is a class of algorithms that can quickly turn samples into an analysis that tells you how prominently ceratin frequencies occur in that sample.  For more check out:

1. Wikipedia: [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)
2. Literate program example:  [Cooley-Tukey FFT](http://en.literateprograms.org/Cooley-Tukey_FFT_algorithm_(C))

This is relevant to your problem because: (1) heart rate is itself a frequency, and (2) most of the sound that comes through the body that you can measure  will be within a certain frequency range.  Dropping frequencies outside this range means dropping all or mostly noise.

Good luck!

Comment: i have seen in apple's auriotouch example can you tell me that what is the frequency of heartrate and how do i drop all frequencies other than heart rate.Have you seen auriotouch sample.If not please have a look and tell me where to change the code and help me to achieve the result.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I've seen various implementations. Some of them use the accelerometer to detect minute movements in your arm/hand when you hold the phone, some of them can use the microphone, you could also do a manual 'tap' interface where you tap the screen while checking your own pulse.

Comment: can you post a sample source using microphone